# How exactly do backpacks work?

Tags: dnd-5e, equipment, encumbrance

So I've always assumed that you just add the backpack weight (5 lbs not the carry weight which is 30 lbs) to my cleric that has a carry weight of 255 lbs if my character was carrying nothing but the backpack I would be carrying 5 lbs of my total 255 lbs but do I leave out the weight of the full backpack or do I add that to how much I'm carrying (like 35 lbs out of 255 lbs)

Comment: To clarify, you're saying a 5 lb backpack with 200 lbs worth of equipment would only count as 5 lbs toward your total weight carried, and not 205 lbs?

Answer (score 9):

Unless the backpack is magical in some way or otherwise states, the weight of the backpack is 5 pounds PLUS the contents of the backpack. It does not reduce the weight, merely makes it more convenient to carry.

Comment: This is correct - but it might be worth explaining that the advantage of a backback is that it gives a character narrative permission to carry a larger number of objects - which is to say, that if a character doesn't have a backback or other container to put things in, they can only carry whatever they can plausibly hold in their arms, which probably weighs much less than their carry weight limit.